# Eclipse shows errors but I can't find them

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to run my project, but Eclipse is saying I have errors. But there are no errors, just a red cross where the project name is. I have tried deleting the R.java and generating a new one, but that didn't work.

Comment: If they are xml file related try going to "problems" deleting the errors from there and rebuilding.

Comment: What is the specific error in the "Error Log" view in Eclipse?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Based on the error you showed ('footballforum' is missing required Java project: 'ApiDemos'), I would check your build path.  Right-click the footballforum project and choose **Build Path > Configure Build Path**.  **Make sure ApiDemos is on the projects tab of the build path options.**

Comment: Help, I can't add things to the project tab.

Comment: Ya, there is no project in the Build path! I need to add one.

Answer (score 148):

Take a look at

```
Window → Show View → Problems
```

or

```
Window → Show View → Error Log
```

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
Project 'footballforum' is missing required Java project: 'ApiDemos' footballforum  Build path Build Path Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved footballforum  Unknown Java Problem

Comment: @JonniBravo Please add the comment above to your original question.

Comment: having a similar problem here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23818242/eclipse-project-window-shows-error-but-code-editor-shows-no-error pleas help.

Answer (score 27):

This happens from time to time in Eclipse. In the "Project" menu there's a "Clean" option, that usually takes care of the problem.

Comment: This worked to clear errors I knew I'd fixed. Actual errors still showed normally.

Answer (score 15):

For me, this happens with Maven and Eclipse/STS whenever I update my IDE or import an existing Maven project. Go to the "Problems tab" (**Window** -> **Show View** -> **Problems**) and see what it says. Recently, the problems tab showed `Project configuration is not up-to-date ...` and suggested that I use Maven to update my project configuration, and this solved the "red X" problem. To do this, in the "Project Explorer" view, trigger the context menu and select **Maven** -> **Update Project**, as seen in this screenshot:

[image: trigger the context menu and select Maven -> Update Project]

Answer (score 13):

Go to `project>clean` and select the project which display error from check box and click ok , it will clear the error for you. 
Click the tab which display build automatically in the project menu
And if this also does not work than restart the eclipse and try again it will work.

Comment: This worked for me when STS was misbehaving. Note that Maven>Clean will *not* fix the problem, you need to do Project>Clean... as shown here

Comment: resolved unnecessary error

Answer (score 7):

If you see the error in problem panel it will say : Description Resource    Path Location Type
Project configuration is not up-to-date with pom.xml. Select: Maven->Update Project... from the project context menu or use Quick Fix.

**Solution : Right click on project > select : Maven->Update Project**

Error gone.

Answer (score 2):

Right Click on Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path. Check if Maven Dependencies is there in list, if not then update maven project by 
Right Click on Project -> Maven -> Update Project

Comment: Hi Modi , what does this mean and do ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a red X on a folder, but not on any of the files inside it. The only thing that fixed it was clicking and dragging some of the files from the problem folder into another folder, and then performing `Maven -> Update Project`. I could then drag the files back without the red X returning.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have Project | Build Automatically flagged. I ran into this issue too and turning that on fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed all the private libraries in JavaBuildPath and added the jars again.. It worked

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue while working on  a selenium project(maven). The Project folder and pom.xml were showing red cross symbol. This was coming as i had the test datasheet open. I could remove the error by just closing the datasheet and the never faced the issue again

Answer (score 0):

In my Spring Boot application, I right-clicked on my Application class -> run as -> Java Application -> Proceed(All errors will be cleared)