# Eclipse project window shows error but code editor shows no error

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jakarta-ee

For my jsp file, the code editor shows no error, but the projects window shows an error. I built my project again, cleaned the project, restart eclipse twice and summoned cthulhu. But my project still shows an error. How do I find the cause and fix the problem ?

**Eclipse project -**

[image]

**JSP file -**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>    
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@ taglib prefix="mine" uri="DiceFunctions"%>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>

${mine:rollIt()}

</body>
</html>
```

**TLD file -**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
<tlib-version>1.2</tlib-version>

<uri>DiceFunctions</uri>
<function>
<name>rollIt</name>
<function-class>foo.DiceRoller</function-class>
<function-signature>
int rollDice()
</function-signature>
</function>
</taglib>
```

Note - look at my project structure. Make a folder foo under web-inf/classes and put the dice class file inside foo. Otherwise the project won't work.

Comment: What does the problems view tell you?... aside from not catching a SummoningCthulhuException...

Comment: Check the Problems tab.

Comment: @ChrisGerken - I opened the problems window by going to Eclipse > Window > Show view > Other > "enter problems" > problems > ok. I see the problem `foo.DiceRoller cannot be resolved to a type`. How do I make this work ?

Comment: Did you include the `jstl.jar` in your library?

Comment: @Braj - you mean under Java Resources > Libraries > Apache Tomcat vXXX >... ? No. I see many jars like jasper, tomcat, servlet-api.jar etc., but no jstl.jar. I thought eclipse will do all that for me when i create a `dynamic web project`. How do I add a jar to that specific folder ? I know how to add jars to a project in eclipse though.

Comment: No you have to put it under `WEB-INF/lib`. just download it.

Comment: What is `Dice.java` doing inside WEB-INF/classes? There must be `Dice.class`.

Comment: @Braj - I looked under src > foo. Saw the java code and class file. Copied the class file and pasted it into web-inf, but java file got copied instead. Great. I'll try copying the class into web-inf.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**How I solved the problem -** I was lucky that my fluke worked. First, copy all the code correctly from the book. Do NOT create any classes folder inside web-inf for your project. In eclipse jee, create a new dynamic web project. Copy all the folders for jsp, html, java code etc from your old project into the new one. Delete your old project. Build your new project (try to also close-open eclipse to be safe). Your project should be error free now. I have no explanation for why this worked.

**Alternately**, if your goal is to learn J2ee JSP etc. quickly, then I suggest that you avoid using Eclipse initially and make your web app folders manually.

Create the following directory structure with all the necessary files:

```
C:\APACHE-TOMCAT-7.0.00\WEBAPPS\SAMPLEAPP
¦   MyHtml.html
¦   MyJsp.jsp
¦
+---WEB-INF
    ¦   DiceRoller.tld
    ¦   web.xml
    ¦
    +---classes
        +---foo
                Dice.class
```

Now put all the necessary code for these files and it will work for sure. The moral of this story is that Eclipse is not good to learn the basics of J2EE/Jsp/Servlets. Make your
web app folders manually. I wasted 2-3 hours in trying to make the eclipse version and still failed. I followed the non-eclipse approach and the code was running in 5 minutes.
And...there was no need to import any jars or extend any classes etc.

Comment: why the -1 ? please tell me.

Comment: Borat, it looks like you created your project structure inside the webapps folder of tomcat. This is something you should avoid. Your project source files should be outside of the tomcat folder. You can setup eclipse to build a war which is put into the webapps folder when you want to deploy your project.

However, the -1 did not come from me.

Comment: @Fortega - my book tells me to do it that way. Is that how professional developers do it ?

Answer (score 1):

- First have you defined `taglib` in *web.xml* as shown below?

  ```
   <jsp-config>
      <taglib>
         <taglib-uri>DiceFunctions</taglib-uri>
         <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/diceRoller.tld</taglib-location>
      </taglib>
   </jsp-config>
  ```
- Second the lib folder is empty in you project snapshot that means you have not added `jstl.jar` in your project.

---

It should look like

```
public class DiceRoller {
    public int rollDice() {
       return 1;
    }
}
```

Find a sample code here on [JSP custom tag function example](http://www.xinotes.net/notes/note/1756/)

---

> When I run the html file on tomcat, i get an error - HTTP Status 404 - /MyJSP/html/MyHtml.html

### Exporting Web Archive (WAR) files

A Web archive (WAR) file is a packaged Web application that can be exported to test, publish, and deploy the resources developed within a Web project.

To export a WAR file from a Web project, do the following:

- Right click on a Web project folder and select Export from the pop-up menu. Then select WAR file in the Export window and then select Next.
- Specify the Web project you want to export (this field is primed if you used the pop-up menu to open the wizard), and specify a location for the new WAR file
- Optional: Optionally, supply WAR export Options, such as whether or not to include Java™ source files in the WAR, and whether to overwrite any existing resources during the export process. Source files are not usually included in a WAR file, because they are not necessary for the server to run the web application.
- Click Finish.

Read more about [Exporting Web Archive (WAR) files](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftwcrewar.html)

Comment: No, I did not because my book does not tell me to do so. But, I put your code in my web.xml now and it still gives me the same error even after building and cleaning the project.

Comment: Can you try it again after removing `${mine:rollIt()}` line. just for testing.

Comment: Yes, the project is error free after removing the EL code.

Comment: Now look at my post or post your code for DiceRoller.

Comment: The method name should be `rollDice()` in DiceRoller class.

Comment: In my book, dice roller class extends nothing. I rubbed my eyes and checked it twice.

Comment: What book are you referring? Try it now. Have a look at the link that I shared in my post.

Comment: Thanks. I am using "Head first JSP and Servlets." If only they had less fluff and more code. Anyway, I run a html file which is supposed to forward the request to the jsp. When I run the html file on tomcat, i get an error - `HTTP Status 404 - /MyJSP/html/MyHtml.html`

Comment: It's a nice book. The error will be gone  without using `SimpleTagSupport` as well.

Comment: In the above URL, you see `MyJSP`. `MyJSP` is the name of the original project which i copied to make the project i showed in the question, i.e `WebProject`. Why does this url still refer to the original project ? I thought I had changed that properly in server.xml

Comment: Thanks Braj. The error is gone after doing all the steps you mentioned. I wonder why my book does not mention all these things.

Comment: just copy `WebContent` of the project into tomcat `webapps` and `rename` it to `MyJSP`. **Don't** copy the whole project.

Comment: Right click on the project -> Export -> war and then deploy the war on tomcat. In that case you don't need to copy the classes from build folder to WEB-INF/classes folder as your mentioned.

Comment: thanks again braj. Isn't there a simple copy paste to copy the class files into web-inf ?

Comment: Follow the standard and really its very simple task of 2-3 clicks.

Comment: I a now learning how to deploy a war onto tomcat with eclipse.

Comment: Will you ask your all the question in the same post? :)

Comment: Read about [Installing Apache Tomcat Server](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/1.5/tutorials/InstallTomcat/InstallTomcat.html)

Comment: check this one as well [Tutorial: Using Tomcat 6 with Eclipse](http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/eclipse.html)

Comment: haha. I understand how frustrating this must be for you. I think I'll add a bounty to this later and try to select your answer. Does that work ?

Comment: Actually I am going to sleep. I am so tired. Good night.

Comment: Have a nice sleep. I will try to fix this and get back.